# Why is "_main" symbol not found when .exe file is loaded in x64dbg?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, symbols, ollydbg

Writing a simple hello_world.c program, and compile with 32-bit MinGW, the
`objdump` can show symbol table using:

```
objdump -t hello_world.exe
```

And the symbol table then have an entry for `_main` as:

```
...
[ 32](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 1) 0x00000460 _main
...
```

However, when loading the `hello_world.exe` file in `x64dbg` debugger, the
`_main` symbol is not shown, as can be seen from the symbol list below
when `hello_world` module is selected.

[image]

[image]

This is annoying, since I would like to create a breakpoint at start of user
code in `hello_world`, and using the symbols to jump to the start location
would be very convenient.

Any idea on how to get the `_main` symbols included in the symbol list?

Comment: I don't know x64dbg but you seem to have listed the imported symbols (or maybe you just showed those in the image but you have others too?)

Comment: @Jester: Updated the question with image showing that the "hello_module.exe" was selected to show the symbols.  Since `_main` is declared in that module, and also listed by `objdump`, I would expect that it was shown in the list.

Comment: But all items in list are of type import. _main would not be type import.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw: Thanks, I see what you mean.  However, the list is complete, so there are no other types than "Import", so for some reason x64dbg does not show local symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While PE has support for storing debug information, the symbol table is mostly an ELF concept.

If you look at the PE sections (use [objdump -h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543487/why-so-many-additional-sections-in-the-pe-file-after-compiling-by-dev-c)) you'll see a lot of extra sections not referenced in the PE directories.
These are used by the binutils to extract the [DWARF information](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/26/the-contents-of-dwarf-sections) and show you, for example, the symbol table.

x64dbg is a pure Windows/PE tool and doesn't understand DWARF.
However, it will show you the address of the PE entry-point (rarely the address of the "`main`" itself though) and will put a breakpoint there for you automatically.
The Entry-point is shown under the export symbols of the binary under inspection.

[image: Entry-point of the PE with an automatic breakpoint, shown in the exported symbols of the binary]

Furthermore, x64dbg will break on  'ntdll` allowing you to reach the entry-point with a ninja use of CTRL+F9 (beware of TLS initialization callbacks).

To get to `main` you can step through the code until you find a call to an address in the `.text` section or simply a call followed by two calls to `cexit` and `ExitProcess`.

Also, given the offset of `_main` retrieved with `objdumpt -t` the VA of `_main` is is `BASE ADDRESS` + `.text RVA` + `__main OFFSET`.
In my case, this was `4010460h`

[image: The call to the <code>main</code> is followed by a call to <code>cexit</code> and <code>ExitProcess</code>]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  I appreciate the many leads to topics I must learn more about in order to understand all the details in the answer. However, the answer appears to address the question, so I chose to accept it :-D